# If statement within an input field

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, react-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap with React and there is an option within an `input`  `<input ... readonly/>` field to set `readonly`, now I have an input field set to `readonly`. However, when the user clicks on a button, I want the readonly mode to disappear and the user to be able to use that input field. However, my if statement does not work. What is the best way to do this?

What I tried

```
{ clicked ?
   readOnly : null
}
```

My Code

```
const Profile = () => {

const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(true);
const onClickBack = () => {
    setClicked(false);
}


return (
    <div>

          <div className="form-group">
              <div className="col-xs-4">
                <label for="exampleInputName">Name</label>
                  <input
                         type="text"
                         className="form-control" 
                         placeholder="Name"
                      // THIS IS WRONG  ↓                            
                      { clicked ?
                            readOnly : null
                      }
                      // THIS IS WRONG  ↑                              
                                                    
                  />
             </div>
           </div>
           <button
              type="button"
              id="submit"
              name="submit"
              className="btn btn-primary submit-button ml-5"
              onClick={onClickBack}
               >
              Back
           </button>

    </div>
);
};

export default Profile;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work...

```
<input readOnly={!clicked}/>
```